# Illustrate interaction between main variable and interaction variable in R

Tags: r, ggplot2, mixed-models

```
library(ggplot2)
library(lme4)
library(lmerTest)
library(jtools)

set.seed(123)

# create data frame with 1000 rows for 100 participants with 2-5 visits
n_participants <- 100
n_visits <- sample(2:5, n_participants, replace = TRUE)
n_rows <- sum(n_visits)
df <- data.frame(
  subnum = rep(1:n_participants, times = n_visits),
  visit = unlist(lapply(n_visits, seq_len)),
  zatt_new = rnorm(n_rows, mean = 0, sd = 1),
  exposure = sample(0:1, n_rows, replace = TRUE),
  years = sample(0:1, n_rows, replace = TRUE),
  BMI = rep(rnorm(n_participants, mean = 25, sd = 2), times = n_visits),
  Age = rep(rnorm(n_participants, mean = 75, sd = 5), times = n_visits)
)
#view(df)

m <- lmer(zatt_new ~ exposure*years +BMI+Age+visit+(1+visit|subnum), data=df, na.action = na.omit)
summ(m)
```

How can I create a ggplot in R to illustrate the interaction between a dichotomous exposure variable (with two levels 0/1) and a dichotomous interaction variable called "years" (also with two levels 0/1)? Specifically, I want to estimate the effect of the exposure variable on the outcome variable, both with and without the presence of the "years" variable, and I want to depict this graphically. How can I do this?

Comment: What I've shown is not quite "both with and without the presence of the `years` variable", but rather "for `years` ==0 and `years` == 1 separately", which is I *think* what you want?

Comment: @BenBolker, Thanks. Why did you choose to use "pred" to present the figure?

Answer (score 0):

`sjPlot::plot_model` will do this for you:

```r
plot_model(m, terms = c("exposure", "years"), 
   type = "pred")
```

[image: model plot]

If `exposure` were really categorical (rather than a numeric variable that happens to have only two values), you'd get a different plot:

```r
m2 <- update(m, data = transform(df, exposure = factor(exposure)))
plot_model(m2, terms = c("exposure", "years"), type = "pred")
```

[image: model plot, but now with points and ranges]